# NPM: Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-2

Executing This:

```
node .\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js --config scripts/webpack.config.js --display-error-details
```

Produces this error.

I am just testing this at the moment, so application.ts just has this

```
export class Aureus {

    constructor() {
        alert('1');
    }

}
```

The webpack file looks as follows:

```
const globule = require("globule");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const extractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const config = {
};

const configuration = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        "application": 
            "application.ts",
            ...globule.find("aureus/**/*.ts", { srcBase: "./scripts" }),
        ,
        "vendor": [
            "bootstrap",
            "jquery",
            "angular",
            "moment",
            "lodash",
            "ramda",
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "../"),
        filename: "packed.js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            filename: "vendor.js"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "window.jquery": "jquery",
        }),
    ],
    resolve:
    {
        alias: {
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /^((?!\.spec\.ts).)*.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            },
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = configuration;
```

I am getting this error?
`application.ts` is in `./scripts/application.ts`
(same directory as webpack.config.js)

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'application.ts' in 'C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\scripts'
resolve 'application.ts' in 'C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\scripts'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\package.json (relative path: ./scripts)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\package.json (relative path: ./scripts)
    resolve as module
      C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\scripts\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\Github\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\node_modules
        using description file: C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/application.ts)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\node_modules\application.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\node_modules\application.ts.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\node_modules\application.ts.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\Projects\Github\Aureus\Aureus.Web\node_modules\application.ts doesn't exist
```

Comment: did you fix this problem? I have a same problem but I still want to use @ in the import path. @Jim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902895/field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration-when-i-changed-the-i

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you provide an actual `resolve` rule, your imports of anything in the `node_modules` will default to looking in the folder provided to the `context`.

Try this rather:

```
resolve: {    
  modules: [
    /* assuming that one up is where your node_modules sit,
       relative to the currently executing script
    */
    path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
  ]
}
```

Also, make sure that you are referencing your `entry` relative to the `context` like so:

```
"application": "./application.ts"
```

instead of

```
"application": "application.ts"
```

Comment: This helps somewhat, but now I am finding that the globule included files are all being searched for in the node_modules folder.

Comment: no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\Development\Projects\AureusEx\Aureus.Web\node_modules\aureus\services\UrlParserService.ts doesn't exist

Comment: the paths here gave me the runaround big time... thanks for the tips.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Did you manage to solve the problem? If so, how? You can edit my answer :). You're welcome

Comment: Your answer was spot on, helped a lot - thanks! I have multiple entry points and dependencies which made the paths tricky. I am transitioning from legacy js to weppack / es6 imports.

Comment: I can imagine. All the best with the task

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to check your package-lock.json, and assumed that your package version is correct

NPM will give this error when your packages version in incorrect.

Here are three tips:

1. Check Node version: `node -v`
2. Make sure that you already install when you enter the root directory: `npm i`
3. Check the version in package.json files. You may find some questions.

Like so:

```
"eslint": "^5.16.0",
```

Instead of:

```
"eslint": "^4.4.0",
```

Comment: Should nom be npm?

Comment: Yes, it's npm, not nom

Comment: Great! I solved with `npm i vue-eslint-parser --save-dev`then in .eslintrc updated `parserOptions` by replacing: `'parser': '@babel/eslint-parser',` into `'ecmaVersion' : 'latest', 'sourceType'  : 'module'`