# What is preventing this rails/vue project from deploying to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, heroku, relative-path, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm developing a rails/vue application that hasn't been decoupled yet and I'm trying to deploy it to heroku but it keeps failing when heroku tries to compile it. It works fine locally. The error I get is:

remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' in '/tmp/build_f1193978/app/javascript/packs'

remote:        resolve './material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' in '/tmp/build_f1193978/app/javascript/packs'
remote:          using description file: /tmp/build_f1193978/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
remote:            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:            using description file: /tmp/build_f1193978/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css)
remote:              no extension
remote:                Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
remote:                /tmp/build_f1193978/app/javascript/packs/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css doesn't exist
remote:              .vue

After doing some research, I found one answer that looks [promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712434/npm-field-browser-doesnt-contain-a-valid-alias-configuration), but I'm not sure how to use it within my rails project, because I don't know where their answer ought to be applied. I'm importing it like so in main.js in the vue portion of the application:

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import App from '../app.vue'
import Axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import './material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'

I've tried including the module in dependencies as opposed to just devdependencies, I've also had heroku skip pruning of said devdependecies, but neither solution worked. Based on this, my understanding of the problem is that heroku can't find the module, because of relative pathing, but how do I circumvent this? Is there a simple way to switch this particular import to absolute pathing without effecting others and, while where there, why doesn't this effect the other imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the relative path here: `./material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css` you're using a downloaded package for that file, and I doubt it's committed to your repository.

If you want to use the [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont), you should do so according to its documentation:

`npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save` - in your project directory

Then create a folder named `stylesheets` inside your `app/javascript` folder, and add a file called `application.scss` there.

Add these lines inside this file:

```
$material-design-icons-font-directory-path: '~material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/fonts/';
 
@import '~material-design-icons-iconfont/src/material-design-icons';
```

More information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont

I also encourage you to read [Getting Started on Heroku with Rails 6.x](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6) to get a better understanding of the platform and how it interacts with Rails.

Comment: yay! happy it did!

Comment: Say, any chance you could also help me with this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708053/vuetify-css-not-applying-in-heroku

It's similar in that something isn't importing, but I believe it derives from a different problem within the code.